# Insert a variable into a display string in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I saved my translation data in a database, each line contains a language in the twig template ,i set the variable so

```
{% if app.request.getLocale()== 'en' %}
    {% set language = 1 %} 
{%else%}
    {% set language = 0 %} 
{% endif %}
```

i use this for display data from database

```
<p>{{indexpage.0.titpage}}</p>
```

I wanted to use the variable language to change the display

```
<p>{{indexpage.language.titpage}}</p>
```

I have tried it with concatenation and other ways but does not

```
<p>{{indexpage.~language~.titpage}}</p>
```

How i can fix this ,thank very much

Comment: indexpage[languange].titpage

Comment: titpage gets my vote...

Comment: This was what I insisted so   .[      ,many many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's an array you can do this:

```
<p>{{ indexpage[language].titpage }}</p>
```

Comment: I can not mark the answers because I still do not have 15 reputations, when i arrival to 15 reputeations  i mark this respost it ok